# change xml structure with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, mapping

I hava the following structure:

```
<data name="piece-shipment" error-status="0"
        product-name="test" name="Hook" street="Freeway 21" city="Bumphill"/>
```

and the following jaxb annotated model..

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
public class PieceShipment {

    /**
     * The field describes, of the parcel is returned to the origin sender
     */
    @XmlAttribute(name = "product-name")
    private String productName;

    /**
     * recipient information
     */
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RecipientAdapter.class)
    private Recipient recipient;
   .....
}




 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Recipient {

    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
...
}
```

How can I map the relation of PieceShipment to Recipient? They are on the same element level.

I've tried to use Adapters, but the adapter doesn't get called.

Comment: This is something you can't do with JAXB. You don't have a single XML element that can be adapted to another type. The problem is with the original XML structure which isn't relational-modelled.

Comment: So there is no way to map the attributes relational?

Comment: Look at it this way: having a recipient with (hopefully) `name` as the key: what would you do with differing address properties? And if it could be mapped, you'd end up with oodles of Recipient objects all over the place. - Best to keep it as it is, run some processing after unmarshalling everything  to extract and check recipient data; handle duplicate Smiths in different  cities or even same city, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) mapping metadata you can't have the properties from `Recipient` mapped into the same parent element that `PieceShipment` is mapped to.

If you are using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your JAXB provider then you can use our `@XmlPath` extension to accomplish this:

```
@XmlPath(".")
private Recipient recipient;
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about MOXy's XPath mapping extension on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: I've already tested it with EclipseLink MOXy @XMLPath("."), but the Recipient object doesn't get created.. I always recieve a "null". I would be very grateful for an extended answer describing the mapping in details.

Comment: I also annotated the Recipient attributes with @XmlAttribute(name = "product-name")